# Without using jQuery ui how do I get a draggable div position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a time scale div inside drag here div I want drop this timescale div anywhere in the drag here div. And also I want to know the position. Is there any suggestion without using jQuery ui ?

```js
    function funct(e) {
            var id = e.id;
            mouseXY(id);
    }

    function mouseXY(id) {
            //alert(id);
            var x = event.pageX,
            y = event.pageY
            $('#' + id).css({
                top: y, 
                left: x 
            });
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <style>
      .timescalebase {
    margin-top: 13px;
    height: 7px;
    position: relative;
    width:20%;
  height:5px;
        background-color:green;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
  <body>
<div id draghere style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;background-color:red">
                <div id="timebase1"draggable="true"class="timescalebase activelevel1" ondrag=funct(this)>
                    
                </div>
  </body>
    </html>
```

How do I get the left value of the timebase1 div after drop? If I add this value in "left:x+..". here I think I will get the answer. How do I get this value?

Answer (score 0):

you should add the absolute attribute into the tag this allows it to be placed by you , add absolute to anything you want to drag , but i don't recommend it , because if you place it somewhere in dreamweaver , it wont be in the exact place on the browser , you'll have to use trial and error a few times to get it perfect .... inline style 'style="position:absolute'

Comment: position:absolute is not a good one for my code because it make more problems ...give me an  idea to get the left position of the div on drag time or after drag